# Dynamics webquery from url in cells

Tags: vba, excel, dynamicquery, excel-web-query

I searched the internet, but I could not find anywhere a dynamic query from links in cells.
In excel i have webquery which generate this data:

I have data in excel Sheet("CustomReport"):

```
SalesOrder  Value1      Value2      Value3     Links
1           Jonas       Station1    8          https://x.com=1
2           Greg        Station1    5          https://x.com=2
3           Anton       Station1    1          https://x.com=3
...         ...         ...         ...        ...
```

Number of rows in this query is always different when it is refreshed.

And based on this webquery i need generate dynamic webquery in macro.
For example:
DynamicQuery1 save data from report https://x.com=1 to Sheet name "Orders" started from A1 and ending A{X} value (reports have diffrents number of rows).

DynamicQuery2 save data from report https://x.com=2 to the same Sheet "Orders" but started from A{X+1}.

I have such a macro, but it only works for the first row.

Sub Test()

```
Dim URL As String

URL = Sheets("CustomReport").Range("E2").Value

Sheets("Orders").Select
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & URL, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "team2289_2"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = False
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = True
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

And i need refreshing this macro every 1 hour.
Anyone can give me macro based on this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To loop through the cells use:

```
dim c as range, DataSpot as range
set c = Sheets("CustomReport").Range("E2")
while c.value <>""
    url = c.value
    set DataSpot=cells(sheets("orders").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).row+1,1)
    ' Web Query Code goes here
    set c=c.offset(1,0)
wend
```

In your data query, use:

```
Destination:=Range(DataSpot.Address))
```

Comment: i wrote @up full macro, can u help me ?

Comment: I fixed the offset line. I mistyped it originally.

Comment: its not work, because macro download x times only raport from cell "e2"
and i need download 1 times every raport from cells e{x}

Comment: I've added another line: url=c.value.

Comment: url=c.value must be the same line like while or add tab before url = c.value?

Comment: It's within the while loop.

Comment: still download raport from first link 'x' times from cell "e2", but not download report from link from cell "e3,e4" etc.
maybe i dont need while loop, but formula: for each rows in column "e" make webquery ?

Comment: i have quesion - how add command - for new quering macro - clean all rows in Sheet1

Comment: If the solution works, perhaps mark my solution as correct and then post a new question for your next issue

Comment: i posted new issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Sub Test()

```
Dim URL As String

URL = Sheets("CustomReport").Range("E2").Value

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Dim c As Range, DataSpot As Range
Set c = Sheets("CustomReport").Range("E2")
While c.Value <> ""
    Set DataSpot = Cells(Sheets("Sorders").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row + 1, 1)
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & URL, Destination:=Range(DataSpot.Address))
         .Name = "team2289_2"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = False
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
            .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
            .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
            .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
            .WebDisableDateRecognition = True
            .WebDisableRedirections = False
             .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
        Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
Wend
```

End Sub

i put your code and i have debug with:
Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)

What wrong i do ?